# Why the app freezes when loading long data

Tags: android

I have JSON local file in the assets folder like below but more than 10,000 objects, When I read them It takes more than 40 seconds and freezes the app so can someone explain how I can do it in Asynctask?

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "T........",
    }
  ]
}
```

*Code*

```
try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("LocalTest.json");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            String Categories = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Categories);
            for (int x = 0; x < jsonObject.getJSONArray("result").length(); x++) {
                //Put data in array
            }
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't have any background of Asynctask so can someone help to convert it?

Optional: If that was possible to add progress and show percent I'll be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynctask is deprecated now. However, you can use a Thread for example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    readJSON();
}

private void readJSON() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("LocalTest.json");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                inputStream.read(buffer);
                inputStream.close();
                String Categories = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Categories);
                for (int x = 0; x < jsonObject.getJSONArray("result").length(); x++) {
                    //Put data in array
                }
                onReadJSONFinished();
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void onReadJSONFinished() {
    // Do what you want when your data is loaded
}
```

Comment: Use that inside onCreate?

Comment: If you need to read your JSON file at the creation of your Activity, then yes.

Comment: How can I know when finish to hide progress dialog?

Answer (score 0):

rather than creating new thread, You have to use AsyncTask class it is for special class for Android background task. Your code snippet could be like below dude.

create a new class called FileReadAsyncTask

```
public class FileReadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("LocalTest.json");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                inputStream.read(buffer);
                inputStream.close();
                String Categories = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Categories);
                for (int x = 0; x < jsonObject.getJSONArray("result").length(); x++) {
                    //Put data in array
                }
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
            super.onCancelled(result);
        }

    }
```

and then call from MainActivity or another class

```
 new FileReadAsyncTask ().execute((Void) null);
```